# Bitonic Program to find the maximum of two numbers

Tags: code-golf

A bitonic program is a program every string of which is bitonic.

A bitonic string is a string S with S[0]<= . . . <=S[k]>= . . . >=S[n-1] for some k, 0<=k< n. (n is the length of the string)

**Examples of Bitonic strings:**

- abcd
- dcba
- vyzcba
- adgf

The goal is to write the shortest bitonic program to find the maximum of two numbers.

**Note:**

- Two group of characters separated by one or more spaces(' '), tabs('\t'), backspaces or line-break('\n') are considered as two different strings.
- Comments in the code are not allowed.
- Other than tabs, spaces, backspaces or line-breaks, the code must contain at least 3 other characters.

**EDIT:**

- Inbuilt function not allowed.
- Conditional statements not allowed.
- <(less than) and >(greater than) signs not allowed

Comment: so... do we choose `k`? for every string? where does `k` come from? examples of bitonic strings? this problem is really unclear.

Comment: @Doorknob added the examples.

Comment: @all: Got downvotes!! Forgot to add some conditions. Please update your codes

Comment: uhh... no. Your edit doesn't make sense. Point one: what exactly counts as inbuilt? Pretty much any printing function is built-in. Also, why block conditional statements? Also, do for-each loops count as conditional statements? If `<` and `>` are not allowed, are `gt` and `lt`? Or are we forced to do comparison via subtraction and checking the sign? In Assembly, does that mean that `CMP` is not allowed while `SUB` is, even if their only difference is that the former doesn't write back? Are we allowed to use `<` and `>` for other things than comparison (say, bit shift or IO)?

Comment: And no, "please update your codes" doesn't work like that. Please use the sandbox the next time, and don't go invalidating existing solutions by introducing extra unreasonable restrictions because you "forgot" them. These are not loopholes you forgot to patch. These are game changers. Voting to close.

Comment: @JanDvorak perfectly fine. This will teach me some lesson.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a chameleon question.

Answer (score 2):

### APL, 3

```
⎕⌈⎕
```

Can this be beaten?

Comment: Too bad two of the three characters don't display for me (unless they're meant to be rectangles). Can you give out a textual description?

Comment: @JanDvorak They ARE rectangles ([image](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2395/index.htm))